# Segmentation fault using composer to create-project symfony on OSX 10.9.2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying out [Symfony2](http://symfony.com) for my next php project. From the directions in the [Book](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_book_2.4.pdf?v=4), I downloaded composer then used this command to create my project on my development Mac OSX 10.9.2 system:

```
$ php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Chaap
```

/usr/local/zend/bin/php: line 4: 51827 Segmentation fault: 11  $ZCE_PREFIX/bin/php.bin -c $ZCE_PREFIX/etc/php.ini "$@"

Erring out with a Segmentation fault: 11.

I used the same command on my hosted Linux testing server:

```
$ php -c ~/public_html composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Chaap
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.4.3)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.4.3)
...
```

And this works. I took a look at the version of php on both:

Versions on the Macintosh:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jan 28 2014 01:25:48) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Extension Manager v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2014, by Zend Technologies
    - with Zend Data Cache v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Job Queue v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Utils v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Optimizer+ v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Code Tracing v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2009-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Monitor v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Debugger v5.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2009, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Page Cache v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]

$ /usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 24 2013 11:31:16
```

Versions on the Linux box:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2014 13:05:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies

$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 11 2014 12:59:55
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.24.11 rev9999 +cloudlinux
```

My current workaround is to create the project on the testing machine, then copy it back to my development machine. But there may be other issues on my Macintosh that will cause other problems down the line. Has anyone seen and resolved this problem?

The macintosh is using ZendServer 6.3 CE
The testing machine is using whatever it's current cpanel is using
The production machine is using ZendServer 6.3

Thank you for your attention.

**Update 2014-04-13**

Workaround #2. Using the builtin php from osx 10.9.2.

1. Install memchche and acp using macports: [here](http://www.gigoblog.com/2013/11/14/install-memcache-and-apc-on-mavericks-server-3-mac-os-x-10-9/)
2. Install intl.so using macports: `sudo port install php54-intl`

Now the version of the built-in php:

```
sh-3.2# /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

And the create-project:

```
$ /usr/bin/php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Symfony
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.4.3)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.4.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

Created project in Symfony
...
```

Still have not solved the problem with create-project and ZendServer 6.3

Comment: Well, I develop in a MBA OSX 10.9.2 (PHP 5.5 with macports) without problems, but let me share something with you... Composer drains your RAM when it comes to calculate dependencies during update (https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898) so my PHP is cofigured to use 1Gb. I run the update in my MBA, upload the composer.locks to the server and execute install there to avoid problems since is a very cheap one. Is not the same scenario but who knows...

Comment: @coma I took the PHP memory from 512M to 6000M. Still get the Segmentation fault. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Updated question by adding workaround #2 - using the built-in php in OSX 10.9.2

Comment: was stuck with the same error message, my solution was using `sudo su` and doing `php composer.phar install` as sh-3.2# ... php -v was identical

Comment: @jook I've also tried this under sudo... My current env is Zend 6.3 Server, php 5.5. I am still using workaround #2 (using the built-in php 5.4).

Answer (score 0):

as said, I had the same issues and for me it was definetly an error with my permissions, which is why executing composer.phar with sudo worked.

My Problem was, that all my projects were placed directly into the `htdocs` folder. Instead of that I placed in a symlink `htdocs` which pointed to another folder inside my basic `User` folder. And tada - works now without sudo. This is because the path to and `htdocs` itself has `root` as owner and `wheel` as group (at least in my case) and the permissions given were not sufficient to execute composer as a user.

Hope this helps someone ;)

Comment: I've been building symfony in my ~/Sites folder, not /var/web/htdocs. I'll try creating a symlink in /var/web/htdocs to my ~/Sites/Chaap and give it a try. Thank you.